# how can I create jquery based submenu tabs?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I would like to create jquery based navigational menu in which my main menu is on the left hand side and on click my submenu items should ne display in the main content area in tabs . I am able to achieve it in Ext-js but how to do it using jquery.

for eg. if you visit http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and clicking on the left menu ...other items displayed on the right side ..but i don't wanna use the tree structure instead of that I will just gonna use tabs or buttons and submenu items need to change on clicking main menu items...

Can anyone direct me to an example ?

Thanks!!
edit: updated layout achieved through ext js  https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2ItQ.png

Comment: jQuery UI Tabs do pretty much exactly what you want: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Thanks! Pat..I have gone through the Jquery UI tabs tutorial but how can I communicate with my main left side navigation menu ...seems to be bit tricky...any examples from which I can start building that layout?

Comment: I think, to answer that - we will need some sample code (or at least an idea of your layout)

Comment: please see the image in my question...taht layout I have done using EXT-JS library...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great with jQuery, so I can't really give you a good answer. But I've been using this site, and they have a bunch of tutorials for menus that could help you.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: Thanks! Phil ..I use that site too...but my requirements were little different ...I have posted my EXT-JS layout comp...I have achieve it easily with EXT-JS but never used jquery for any layout so not sure about how to achieve that ....